# How to call jQuery function in HTML <body> onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call a jQuery function from an HTML `<body>` tag. Here's my HTML:

```
< body bgcolor="#ffffff" onLoad="???" >
```

How would I call a jQuery function when the page is loaded? My jQuery function looks like this

```
jQuery(function($){
    var input_id;
    //code
});
```

Comment: Might be answered already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: `jQuery(function($)` does exactly that. No need for an onload handler.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is in the question.

Answer (score 13):

whatever code you write in the below method(block) would be executed automatically after the DOM load. **You need not call this from HTML component again.**

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

//your code
});
```

Comment: @isherwood . OP is expecting that the method needs to be called from HTML which is not required. Check his question.   < body bgcolor="#ffffff" onLoad="???" > . which I have addressed. Don't know why it is down voted?

Comment: so including this in the script of my html would cause it to automatically run when page loads? And is that all I have to do? 

do I need to include jQuery( like I did in my original question anywhere?

Comment: @user3822248 that is all you are supposed to do. jQuery is just an alternative to '$' sign. $ is short notation for jQuery

Answer (score 3):

This topic has been covered here before.

You are most likely looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var input_id;
    //code
})
```

Or

```
$(window).load(function($) {
    var input_id;
    //code
});
```

If you are curious about the difference between these two, see the [JQuery documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) on the topic.

Also note that `<body onload="">`, which you seem to be trying to use, [is generally not compatible](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) with the above JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

HTML: **You're on the right track,** but you do not have to have put JS in the body tag. See the JS options below:

```
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function($) {
    functionA(arg1, arg2, arg3);
});
```

This will fire up `functionA()` once the `DOM` including graphics have fully loaded.

OR

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    functionA(arg1, arg2, arg3);
});
```

This will fire `functionA()` once the `DOM` has loaded and before any graphics finish loading.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    // code
});
```

This is shorthand for document.ready() so it will wait for the body to finish loading before executing.

Answer (score 0):

As of Jquery 3, the following syntax is depreciated:

```
document.ready(function(){
   //code
});
```

The recommended alternative in Jquery 3 is to use the following syntax (which in previous versions was just considered a shorthand syntax):

```
$(function(){
    //code
});
```

Here is is the official Jquery explanation for why the first syntax was depreciated and is no longer recommended (https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> ... The selection [of document] has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.ready(function($){
  // here you go
})
```

Comment: Sorry, the Original Poster.

Comment: Try to be more descriptive. Your imaginative acronyms may not be so famous :P

Comment: It's fairly common on SO (Stack Overflow). :-)